# MKMapView zoomed out when setting region programmatically

Tags: swift, uikit, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to recenter MKMapView to user's current location programmatically.

Following is the code for map view recenter.

```
fileprivate func recenterToCurrentLocation() {
    var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: self.mapView.region.span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

When I zoom-in MKMapView to max level manually by touch/pinching, and then try to hit "Recenter" button (Which actually runs the code mentioned above). The new region in little bit zoomed out. it is not same as previous one.

I am trying to recenter MKMapView without changing zoom-level.

But only when zoom-in level is at maximum, I am getting this issue.

Setting region programmatically also changing the zoom level.

**This is happening only in iPad, on iPhone, same code is working just fine.**

Following is how my ViewController looks like.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func recenterButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    recenterToCurrentLocation()
}

fileprivate func recenterToCurrentLocation() {
    var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: self.mapView.region.span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}
```

**Following is the screen shot with max zoom-in on current location by Touch/Pinch**
[image: MaxZoomImage]

**Following is the screen shot when I hit Recenter button at bottom right corner screen which eventually runs recenter code when I am setting MKCoordinateRegion**

You can clearly see that this one has slightly bigger visible reason.

[image: RecenteredScreenShot]